# PK duplicate key error, but no such key in my db

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, primary-key

I'm using .net, C# , LINQ, SQL Server 2012.

this work basically just insert many data into  DB.

I found i missed about 7,000 rows  over total 85,000 rows.

Then i go debug , i found there are some data with real duplicate key .

But most of their key is no existed in DB and the DB also return  error as duplicate key.

any ideas please?

code is like this

```
    try
    {
        resCnt++;
        dbconn.table.AddObject(newRow);
        dbconn.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DB fail ID:"+ newRow.id);
        List< table> testRepeat=(
            from da in dbconn.table
            where da.id==table.id
            select da
            ).Take(1).ToList();

        if (testRepeat.Count() > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+ "Repeated ID: " + table.id+" Saved at "+testRepeat.First().LastModified);
            repeatCnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!!terrible!!");
        }
```

there are  some ids: `322476,438095 ....`
the fist 322476 is exised , so the error say `"322476 duplicate key "` as usual

but when i get `438095` to `dbconn.SaveChanges();`
the 438095 is no existed
it will go to the exception part the inner error still saying `"322476 duplicate key... "`
which at least should be "438095 duplicate key... "

then i click the variable row.id ,  it  is  438095 ...

Comment: Are you using auto-incrementing identities? If so you'll want to turn off identity insert. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you.

I find a Solution, that is 
when i find the Duplicate key error come out for the first time.
which means real Duplicate key.

i re-establish database connection by:

```
                dbconn.Dispose();
                dbconn = new Entities();
```

then this will work

thanks a lot! 
hope this will help others